# Fabric ssh twice within host

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

How do I ssh twice if server2 can only be accessed from server1?

fabfile.py:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import env

env.hosts = ['host@server1.com']

env.use_ssh_config = True

def dothis():
    run('ssh host@server2.com')
    run('ls -al') # this should be done on host@server2.com
```

When I run:

fab dothis, I get:

```
[host@server1.com] Executing task 'dothis'
[host@server1.com] run: ssh host@server2.com
[host@server1.com] out: Permission denied (publickey).
[host@server1.com] out: 
[host@server1.com] out: 

Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 255 while executing!

Requested: ssh host@server2.com
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "ssh host@server2.com"

Aborting.
Disconnecting from host@server2.com... done.
```

How do I tell fabric to env.user_ssh_config = True on server2 without keeping another fabric file on server1?

The way I usually access server2 is like this:

```
ssh host@server1.com ssh host@server2.com
```

Comment: sorry for that fixed now, do want post that as an answer? Would that require 2 tasks?

Comment: Added as an answer. Only the one task should be required to do what you have in your question.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try running the command with [sshpass](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) from `server1.com` to skip host key checking. Your command should look something like this: `sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no host@server2.com "ls -al"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use "`server1.com`" as a [`gateway`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/env.html#gateway) host to "`server2.com`", and presumably others:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import env

env.gateway = 'host@server1.com'
env.hosts = ['host@server2.com']

env.use_ssh_config = True

def dothis():
    run('ls -al')  # this should be done on host@server2.com
```

Comment: I get paramiko.ChannelException: Administratively prohibited. Not sure what went wrong there. Do need to do something on server1 for it to be used as a gateway like this?

Comment: @Jimmy: Did you get this working? If not, I suspect you have some port-forwarding configured for `server2.com` in your `.ssh/config`. Try working with a minimal .ssh/config and adding in only the necessary lines to get this example working. You shouldn't need to do any special configuration on the hosts for this example. Good luck!